# DispatchSourceTimer how to execute after repeating time

Tags: swift

I have a timer:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.domain.app.timer")
timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: queue)
timer.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: 30.0, leeway: .seconds(0))
...
timer.resume()
```

It works perfect except one thing. Timer executes first iteration after my **timer.resume()**. But I need to execute first iteration **after repeating time** (in my case 30 seconds). How to do this?

Comment: What about `deadline: now() + 30` ?

Comment: @MartinR hm, it works. I was sure it will executed twice. You may answer and I will mark the answer as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `deadline` parameter determines the first delivery time (subject
to timer coalescing, leeway, ...), and the `repeating` parameter
determines the interval after the first delivery.

Therefore

```
timer.schedule(deadline: .now() + 30.0, repeating: 30.0, leeway: .seconds(0))
```

schedules the timer to deliver after 30 seconds, and then again every
30 seconds.